# What is the difference between object assignment '=' and Object.create()

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I am going some deep into javascript object operations.
Here my question is what is a different between `const me = Object.create(person);` and `const me = person;` here both operation gives me a slimier output. I mean it references object to new variable `me`.

```js
const person = {
  isHuman: false,
  printIntroduction: function() {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
  }
};

const me = Object.create(person);

me.name = 'Matthew';  
me.isHuman = true;

me.printIntroduction();

const me2 = person;

me.name = 'Manan'; 
me.isHuman = false; 

me.printIntroduction();
```

In above code I have included both operation direct `assignment` and assign by using `Object.create();`. Here both variable referencing to objects person, but what is different between it? Can some one explain me?
This question might be asked before but I cant find proper explanation. Simple explanation would be appreciated :-).

Comment: If you print out person. You will know the diference

Comment: @user3562932 could you tell me how it would be different in brief?

Comment: i thing Object.create(person) i creating new object instead of assigning reference of object ? is it?

Comment: See the documentation. In particular, the supplied object is used as the prototype _chain_: “The Object.create() method _creates a **new object**, using an existing object as the **prototype [chain]**_ of the newly created object.”

Comment: In both cases an object (new or otherwise) is assigned.

Comment: Assignment means both **me2** & **person** are references to the same object, so if you need to instantiate a new object such as **me** you can assign **me2** to empty object `me2 = {}` then assign person to it or use new keyword `me2 = new Person()`

Answer (score 5):

The first difference is that, when you use regular assignment both of your variables point to the same object, when you edit one, you edit the other. This does not happen with create.

```js
const a = {};
const b = a;

b.do = 100;

console.log(a);

const c = Object.create(a);
c.dodo = 100;
console.log(a)
```

The 2nd difference, is that `Object.create` creates an object which has the first oject as a "prototype". Prototypes are the basis of how objects and inheritance works in javascript, for example when you have an object, it's default `toString` method is in the prototype. See this below

```js
const a = {do : 100};
const c = Object.create(a);
console.log(c.do);
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty("do"));
console.log(c.hasOwnProperty("do"));
```

If yout run the above in a browser console and then log c, you will see that the `do` is in the `__proto__` of `c`. not directly on c.

Whenever you have any object in javascript and call a property or a method on it, javascript will search it on that object an then go up the prototype chain. This allows you to save space so not every object has to carry the shared properties on it.

Fun side note, `{}` has all the functions objects have in its prototype, `null` does not so

```js
const a = Object.create(null);

// works as normal
console.log(a);
a.hello = "hello";
console.log(a);

// error
console.log(a.toString());
console.log(m + m);
```

EDIT : Sorry, slight mistake when you use `Object.create` and the edit the original, you do see the change appear in the prototype of the new.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, `person` is a reference to an object. When you do `Object.create()`, you are creating a new object (i.e., a new reference) from an existing object. This new object has the original  object as a prototype. You assign this new reference to `me`,  and you can  modify it without changing the original `person` object.

On the other hand, `me2 = person`, assigns the reference to the `person` object  to `me2`. This means that `me2` and `person` both  refer to  the same object, and changing one will change the other. You see this in action when you pass objects to  functions.

In short, `Object.create()` should be used when you want to create a new object, and assignment should be used when you want to reference an existing object from a new variable.

Comment: Object.create does not “duplicate” an object. More clarification is needed.

Comment: Object.create() doesnt simply copy, it creates a new object using the original as a prototype

Comment: @QurakNerd yea that was a poor simplification. I adjusted my answer after the  initial comment and removed any language indicating a "copy" effect. Thanks

Comment: Ah yes you did, sorry I didn't see that. I

Answer (score 2):

> The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing
>   object as the prototype of the newly created object [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
>
> Mean when you are doing

```
const me = Object.create(person);
   // you are actually doing  
    me={}
    me.__proto__=person
```

```js
var person = {
  isHuman: false,
  printIntroduction: function() {
  
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
    
  }
};

const me = Object.create(person);
console.log('isHuman is own Property  obj me:'+me.hasOwnProperty('isHuman'))
me.name = 'Matthew';  
me.isHuman = true;

me.printIntroduction();
debugger


const me2 = person;
console.log('isHuman is own Property obj me2:'+me2.hasOwnProperty('isHuman'))


me2.name = 'Manan'; 
me2.isHuman = false; 

me2.printIntroduction();
```